# How to disable back button for certain forms

Tags: forms, navigation, codenameone

I want to disable the "back" button on a specific form, but in other forms (views) continue working.

Comment: I'm assuming this for a GUI builder application? Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the allowBackTo on the statemachine, this method should return true by default so you can keep going back to other forms but return false for those forms which you do not want to allow going back to, for example, if you want to keep going back to all of your forms with the exception of one called "SplashScreen" you should do the following:

```
 @Override
    protected boolean allowBackTo(String formName){
        if ("SplashScreen".equals(formName)){
              return false;
            }
            return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In a specific Form , you can just use inside your Form :

```
removeCommand(getBackCommand());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, is to add a conditional in the `Command` where the `ActionPerformed` method of the functional interface `ActionListener` is implemented.

If the conditions are met, execute the code. In addition you may use an `else` or `else if` block to provide user feedback with `animateLayout` calls.

However, we need to be very careful with this approach, because we do not want to put too much logic in `ActionPerformed` since it will slow execution, degrading performance.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry. Just insert an id or class to the concerned form where you need to disable the button. And use that class or id to disable the button.

Ex: Take '#myid button' as selector

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your answer? Maybe provide a code sample?

Comment: I have a similar issue. @EugeneS. suggests to use `ComponentSelector` to create your `Component` objects, leveraging the `addTags()` method. Then use the jQuery style syntax to obtain object references to any of them from anywhere in your codebase.
I am still looking though for a method to disable a Button until conditions are met, without necessarily removing and adding back the associated `Command`.